# Classifier for data with varying dimensionality

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I need to train a classifier with data whose dimensionality can vary. For example (and this is made-up date for illustration):

```
class-1,0,1,2,3
class-2,0,3,2,4,5,7
class-3,1,8,8,8,2,8,0,0,0
:
:
and so on...
```

I am trying to train a Linear SVM using `scikit-learn` which requires the dimensionality to be fixed. A simple zero-padding of the smaller dims to match the dim of the largest, is giving me disappointing results.

Should I be using a different classifier for such data? How should I approach this?

Comment: What is the nature (origin, real meaning) of your data and what have been the preprocessing steps, if any?

Comment: They are intensity measurements at different points of a surface and rendered an image. So depending on the surface type and conditions, I could have 1..n measurements (where n <1024). Thanks

Comment: I have tried PCA based dimensionality reduction but not sure that's appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Feature hashing** is the algorithm you need to use to convert your variable-length input into constant-length input. Then, you could use your transformed vectors with any appropiate learning algorithm.

[Wikipedia: Feature Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing)

Answer (score 1):

Try padding with feature mean/median, that's another way to deal with missing data. 
Are those measurements made in the same points/features ?